# Can I disable automatic error handling in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, error-handling

In OpenGL, the default setting is to report errors automatically when they occur. They can either be queried using `glGetError` or via an error callback set with `glDebugMessageCallback`.

Doesn't this approach use unnecessary resources when no errors are actually thrown?

To save resources, I'd like to know how to disable this mechanism. I am thinking to disable it in a "release" version of my application, where no errors are expected to be thrown.

Comment: Did you check the OpenGL Wiki page about error handling? Especially the [No error contexts section](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#No_error_contexts)? For release, you could also simply not set a error callback and not call glGetError. Then nothing will be reported.

Comment: @BDL No, thanks for showing me that. Its just what I was looking for. This still however leaves my question about performance overhead of error handling unanswered.

Comment: Well, since you can disable error checking, its safe to assume that error checking introduces a non-zero overhead. How large the overhead is will depend on your GPU, driver, OpenGL implementation and a lot of other factors.

Comment: _@YanB_. I  am supporting @BDL's stance. If you're so hard on limit of resources, the _error handling_ is probably a minor problem with your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's safe to assume that the internal API error checking by OpenGL introduces a non-zero overhead at runtime. How much overhead depends on the actual OpenGL implementation used.

Since OpenGL 4.6, OpenGL allows to create a context without error checking by setting the `GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_NO_ERROR_BIT` flag during context creation.

More details can be found

- In the OpenGL Wiki: [OpenGL Error - No error contexts](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error#No_error_contexts)
- In the [KHR_no_error](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/KHR/no_error.txt) extension description